# Printing Glossaries in amsart using TexStudio

Tags: glossaries, texstudio, amsart, arara

I am trying to make a glossary in an amsart document using TeXstudio but the glossary will not print. I've downloaded xindy, arara, and perl and have tried to use all of them, but to no avail. Any thoughts?

A Minimal example containing all of the relevant packages, etc.:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex    
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[9pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{def1}{name={first definition},description={description1}}
\newglossaryentry{def2}{name={second definition},description={description2}}

\begin{document}
\section{Preliminaries}

This is \gls{def1} and this is \gls{def2}.

\printglossaries
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? Have you remembered to use `\makeglossaries` in your preamble? Has a glossaries log file (`.glg`) been created? If it has, does it have any error messages in it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Also a .glg file has not been created... a .glo one has...

Comment: I get a glossary as expected.

Comment: I don't have `xindy`, so I've removed `[xindy]` from the call to the `glossaries` package. And I, too, get the expected result.

Comment: Are you running it on 'TeXstudio'? Also using 'arara'?

Comment: @user33486 Do you have the file `xindy.yaml` in the arara rules directory?

Comment: Don't think so... How would one do that? Also using a Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `arara` with `xindy` you need to have the `xindy` rule installed. This is a file called `xindy.yaml`. The following is adapted from Paulo Cereda's `texindy.yaml` rule:

```
!config
# Xindy rule for arara
# requires arara 3.0+
identifier: xindy
name: Xindy
command: <arara> xindy @{german} @{language} @{codepage} @{module} @{input} @{options} "@{getBasename(file)}.idx"
arguments:
- identifier: german
  flag: <arara> @{isTrue(parameters.german,"-g")}
- identifier: language
  flag: <arara> -L @{parameters.language}
- identifier: codepage
  flag: <arara> -C @{parameters.codepage}
- identifier: module
  flag: <arara> -M @{parameters.module}
- identifier: input
  flag: <arara> -I @{parameters.input}
- identifier: options
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.options}
```

This file should go in the `rules` directory of `arara`'s installation directory. On Windows, this is probably something like `C:\Program Files\arara`, but if you installed it via TeX Live, it might have gone in TeX Live's `scripts` subdirectory.

**Edit:** Actually, I realise this doesn't answer your question, as you're directly invoking `makeglossaries` rather than `xindy`. Check to make sure you actually have `xindy` installed. Another alternative is to try using [makeglossariesgui](http://ctan.org/pkg/makeglossariesgui) which has diagnostic tools which might help you track the problem.