# Has anyone managed to use \glossaries with TeXstudio on Windows?

Tags: miktex, glossaries, windows, texstudio, xindy

As a new LaTeX user, I have spent some time configuring my system and ironing the usual start-up mistakes. So far, I've been able to compile several documents with indices, graphics, etc. but now I'm trying to add a glossary and I'm absolutely and deeply confused.

I seem unable to make the `\glossaries` (with `xindy`) package work on my TexStudio/Windows 8 - MikTeX 2.9 machine so any help or orientation will be much appreciated.

**Update:**

Xindy seems to be working, now the question is WHAT TO DO NEXT

[image: Xindy working on Windows 8.1]

Now I am trying this MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\author{author}
\title{title}

\begin{document}

test la \gls{IG} es vital en la protección del ternero hay 5 tipos de \glspl{IG}

\newacronym[longplural=Inmunoglobulinas]{IG}{IG}{Inmunoglobulina}

\makeglossaries

\end{document}
```

and the errors on my build result are

- **on pdfLaTeX**

  > `line 21: Can be used only in preamble. \makeglossaries
  >
  >   : \makeglossaries hasn't been used,the glossaries will not be updated.
  >
  >   : No \printglossary or \printglossaries found.`
- **on Makeglossaries command**

  > `Process started: "C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/makeglossaries.exe"  "texstudio_B11540"`
  >
  > `makeglossaries version 2.12 (2014-01-20)`
  >   `added glossary type 'main' (glg,gls,glo)`
  >
  > `No \@istfilename found in 'texstudio_B11540.aux'. Did your LaTeX run fail? Did your LaTeX run produce any output? Did you remember to use \makeglossaries?`
  >
  > Process exited with error(s)

**What Finally Worked**

I followed this path:

1. Installed MiKTeX latest version and updated it
2. Downloaded `xindy-win.exe` and installed it with all the default options
3. Configured TeXstudio as per Khumar's indications with one difference: On `Options>Configure...>Commands` - `Texindy` i used `"C:/Program Files (x86)/xindy/miktex/bin/texindy.exe" %.idx`

and now seems to be working!

Comment: It's never the editor (TeXstudio) itself, it's always the back-end tools (MiKTeX, TeX Live, etc.) the editor calls. What's the simplest possible document you can write that fails to run with `xindy` and `glossaries`? Does `glossaries` work without `xindy`? Is TeXstudio configured to run `makeindex`, `makeglossaries`, or what?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: First of all tell us, how you managed to use `xindy` with MiKTeX.

Comment: I do recommend to _not_ use this out-of-date installer: [How to use Xindy with MiKTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/252845) Could you, please, type in your command prompt the following `echo %path%`? Does show this the **whole** system path, as it should be?

Answer (score 9):

[First ensure that `xindy` works with your distribution.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71167/how-to-use-xindy-with-miktex)

Even though an entry exists for `Make Glossaries` in the build window (see figure below), it doesn't appear under the  `Commands` of `Tools` menu:

[image]

There is no short cut available too. If somebody knows how to make use of this please feel free to edit the answer.

---

## Alternative

You can define a user command:

Go To `Options` → `Configure TeXstudio`. In the window that opens do the following:

1. Choose `Build` and click.
2. Click `Add` under User Commands
3. Fill : `user1: Make Glossaries` and `"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/makeglossaries.exe" %`. You can browse to the exe file also. Note that the path may be different for you. Don't forget the `%` at the end.
4. Press `OK` and come out

Now you will have a user menu for `Make Glossaries` with a short cut:

[image]

Now you can `pdflatex` `Make Glossaries` and `pdflatex`.

[image]

Happy Glossing :)

---

Additional note:

As noted by Speravir, you have to specify `"texindy.bat" %.idx` instead of `texindy.exe %.idx` as in the following window.

[image]

## Edit:

There were some errors in your code. Try this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[acronym,nomain,xindy]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\author{author}
\title{title}

\newacronym[longplural=Inmunoglobulinas]{IG}{IG}{Inmunoglobulina}

\begin{document}

test la \gls{IG} es vital en la protección del ternero hay 5 tipos de \glspl{IG}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When one made `xindy` available for MiKTeX with the tutorial you link in the beginning, then the Texindy entry must be changed to `texindy.bat %.idx` (BAT instead of EXE).

Comment: @Speravir i downloaded a windows installer linked here on another question called xindy-win.exe but im not even sure if it is working. Looks like this is going to be too much for me (timewise) what are the xindy alternatives for windows?

Comment: @Speravir after a reboot (ye old trick) xindy --help on the command line works ... now im not sure about the next steps

Comment: @HarishKumar i applied your suggestions including the aditional note by Speravir but still get compiling errors, have updated the main post showing this

Comment: @Mauro Please see the edit.

Comment: @HarishKumar ... and now it works!!!! im editing my original post to show what worked

Comment: @HarishKumar Of course, using arara would make things easier.

Comment: @egreg i would gladly use `arara` if you let me know what it is or how to use it

Comment: @Mauro See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118890/how-to-configure-texstudio-editor-to-use-glossaries-package-with-makeglossaries and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123472/printing-glossaries-in-amsart-using-texstudio

Comment: @egreg That was the first idea, but then you know... :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem may be because the 'makeglossaries' command (that generates the .gls file) is not called before pdflatex is invoked.

**Step 1**: Make sure that 'Makeglossaries' command is properly defined as "makeglossaries.exe %" under "Commands" option in TexStudio. 
In addition, you may verify whether 'makeglossaries.exe' is available on the system path by typing this on a command prompt.

**Step 2**: Enable '**Show Advanced Options**' and configure your '**Build**' settings in TexStudio to compile pdflatex, make glossary, and compile pdflatex again.

To do this, *replace* your "Build & View" option (that we may typically invoke using keyboard shortcut 'F5') as follows:

Before:

```
txs:///compile | txs:///view
```

After:

```
txs:///compile | txs:///makeglossaries | txs:///compile | txs:///view
```

Answer (score 1):

the solution I found is to change the makeglossaries command by a makeindex one (adapted from https://sites.google.com/site/mcoath/other/latex/pahc) :

> In "Options >> Configure TexStudio >> Commands >> Makeglossaries"

```
makeindex %.acn  -s %.ist -o %.acr
```

Then runs the commands:

> "Tools >> Compile "
>
> "Tools >> Glossary"
>
> "Tools >> Compile "

Hope it works

RMQ: one can track down the effect of glossary command in *main.acr*