# Using Arara on windows in Texstudio to generate glossaries

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, arara

I am trying to generate glossaries in my LaTeX document using the `article` class and am using TeXStudio

I used the below code but nothing gets printed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{culdesac}{name=cul-de-sac,description={passage or street closed at one end},plural=culs-de-sac}

\newacronym{led}{LED}{light-emitting-diode}
\begin{document}
\section{This is my section}

Some text

\end{document}
```

I googled and found out that I would need Arara to generate and print glossaries. I installed Arara.exe under C:\Program Files\arara\

and made a new command based on below link

[How to configure TexStudio editor to use glossaries package with makeglossaries and xindy or how to configure TexStudio to use arara?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118890/how-to-configure-texstudio-editor-to-use-glossaries-package-with-makeglossaries)

But I am getting the error :

Error: Could not start the command: C:\Program Files\arara\arara.exe -v -l "my_text_file"

Can someone help me please?

I just want to print acronyms and glossaries in my article.

Comment: Arara is definitely not *needed* to generate glossaries, it may however make the process easier. Did you read the excellent glossaries manual? What happens if you run arara.exe from your command line?

Comment: Where do i find "excellent glossaries manual", can you provide me with a link. I am getting really frustrated at now being able to generate glossaries and acronyms. Can you help me with a short working example on how to print them in article class?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries, this page has a few PDFs.

Comment: Go to command prompt, and type `arara --version`. What do you get?

Comment: Hi @HarishKumar - its version 3.0

Comment: OK, Then simply try to put `arara -v -l % | | txs:///view`. It should work. This may be useful too: [Has anyone managed to use \glossaries with TeXstudio on Windows?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156278) :)

Comment: Hi @Harish ; Thanks a lot for the link. It was also really helpful ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to differentiate between a) creating glossaries and b) controlling the process from your editor. With b) I can't help as I am not using TeXstudio.

Save the following document under the name `sample.tex` (the name is important!)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=long,toc,acronym=true]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{Perl}{name=\texttt{Perl},sort=Perl,description=A scripting language}

\newacronym{svm}{SVM}{Support Vector Machine}
\newacronym{xml}{XML}{Extensible Markup Language}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\gls{Perl}

\gls{svm}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Run the `sample.tex` through the LaTeX compiler of your choice, I usually use `pdflatex`

Run the next two commands from a) the command line or b) save them in a file with the extension `.bat`

```
makeindex -s sample.ist -t sample.glg -o sample.gls sample.glo
makeindex -s sample.ist -t sample.alg -o sample.acr sample.acn
```

Run LaTeX again on the TeX file. You should get the following PDF:

[image: glossaries]

I nevertheless strongly recommend Nicolas manual, as the above code is a few years old (I took it from my example repository) and things may have changed in the meantime. Concerning `arara` I have created a short description for TeXworks, it may help you as well: http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2928

If you are not able to open a command window and run `arara.exe` I would guess the path setting is somehow corrupt. In this case locate `arara.exe` on your computer and add the directory it is located in to the Windows path variable.

Comment: Hello - Thanks a lot for the detailed reply. It worked like charm ! Much appreciated !